# JAVA SCRIPT var with Double Quotes to PHP and back for Auto fill

Tags: javascript, php, autofill, double-quotes

I have an HTML/PHP form that uses JAVA SCRIPT function to send (POST) an input content to a PHP code which performs a query and gets back to the JAVA SCRIPT function with data to Auto fill additional inputs in the form.

It all **works great** when the input content i send is plain text, even if there is a single quote in the content it works.

BUT, as soon as **double quotes** are included in the input content it fails to return the Auto fill results.

Appreciate your help with indicating where do i fail with passing the quotes.
Thanks

- Just to make it clearer, the code works if customer name is "**Intel**" or "**Int'el**" , but it fails when customer name is "**Int"el**"

Here is the **JAVA SCRIPT** function that sends and receive the data from the PHP:

```
!--Script Auto fill ltd by customer -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatefrm() {
    setTimeout(function(){
            var customer = $('#customer').val();
            if ($.trim(customer) !='') {
            $.post('customerfill.php', {customer: customer}, function(data) {
                $('#customerupdate').val(data['customer']);
                $('#ltdupdate').val(data['ltd']);

                });
               }
    }, 10);
   } 
 </script>
```

Here is the **PHP** code that gets the POST data , performs the query, and sends back the array for the JAVA SCRIPT auto fill:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['customer'])) {

$DB_Server = "localhost"; // MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "XXXX"; // MySQL Username
$DB_Password = "XXXX"; // MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "XXXXXXXX"; // MySQL Database Name

$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL:<br />" . mysql_error() . "<br />" . mysql_errno());
// Select database
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Failed to select database:<br />" . mysql_error(). "<br />" . mysql_errno());
      mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
      mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');


$safe_name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['customer']));

$query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer = '". $safe_name ."' LIMIT 1 ");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    json($row);
} else {
    json(null);
}
}

function json ($array) {
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your js code is fine and i think error in your php code and in that line

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer = '". $safe_name ."' LIMIT 1 ");
```

so you should use PDO Prepared Statements for security and not face problem with double quote

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_database;charset=utf8mb4";
try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "database_username", "database_password");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "no connection";
    exit();
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer = :customer LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array(":customer"=>$safe_name));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: Thank you Sally, tried your solution but no good, now it doesn't even work with single quote in the input content, and of course it still doesn't work with double quotes.

Comment: Hi mark , do you enable pdo extension in your local server or in php.ini ?

Comment: and also replace  SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer = ? LIMIT 1 with parametrized prepared statements   SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer = :customer  LIMIT 1  and replace  $stmt->execute([$safe_name]); with $stmt->execute(array(":customer":$safe_name));

Comment: Yes, its enabled, i am using Raspbian (Debian version of Raspberry pi). Also tried your changes, same thing, it's working fine for lets say "Intel" but for "Int'el" or "Int"el" it doesn't :\

Comment: Today i found out that even two single quotes one after the other (looks like double quotes '') still work, only the double quote fails in my original code. maybe it's something with the JAVA SCRIPT ? can't handle the double quotes and pass them correctly to the PHP ?